# Algorithm to remove unique elements from array and print elements in original order

Tags: algorithm

There is one question which is bugging me, and somehow, I cannot figure out what to do with it. Suppose an array `{9,1,2,4,1,2,2}` is given. The unique elements in the array are `9` and `4`. The output array should be `{1,2,1,2,2}` . 
My idea to preserve the order and find duplicates is to use a LinkedHashMap which will have the entries and the count of occurrence of the entries.

The problem is maintaining the order of the elements. Once I put the entries in the hashMap, the order will vanish.

Comment: How about LinkedLists ?

Comment: Already you mentioned LinkedHashMap sorry, it is linked each other no need to worry about order ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. create a

   HashMap count =new HashMap();
2. iterate your array store the array-value as key and the count of the value as value in the hashmap
3. iterate the array a second time and remove value from the array if count to the key is one.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing making the array vanish. Just iterate over the array, checking whether the value in the map is greater than one.

Answer (score 1):

So an easy way to do this is to first count the number of each element (can be done in `O(n)`), iterate over the counter and put all elements with count = 1 in a set (also in `O(n)`).

Now run through the original list and print all elements that are not in your set (also `O(n)`). So the solution will run in `O(n)` time and space.

And here is 2 line solution in python:

```
from collections import Counter
arr = [9,1,2,4,1,2,2]

unique = {k for k, v in Counter(arr).iteritems() if v == 1}
print [i for i in arr if i not in unique]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just count elements and check if the total count of current element is greater than one.

Code example (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> to_split = {9, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2};

  std::vector<int> unique, not_unique;
  std::unordered_map<int, int> counter;
  for (int elem : to_split) {
    ++counter[elem];
  }
  for (int elem : to_split) {
    if (counter[elem] > 1) {
      not_unique.push_back(elem);
    } else {
      unique.push_back(elem);
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Unique: " << std::endl;
  for (int elem : unique) {
    std::cout << elem << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Not unique:" << std::endl;
  for (int elem : not_unique) {
    std::cout << elem << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Unique:
9 4 
Not unique:
1 2 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just brainstorming a bit, but I somehow have to think about how an unstable sorting algorithm can be made stable: decorate, sort, undecorate.

Given your input list, you iterate over it, adding the position of the item to a list in a map.

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    value = list[i]
    map[value].append(i)
}
```

Then, remove all items with count 1, and reconstruct the list (which you can do, because you have the indices in the map).

Thinking about it further: why not just do 1 loop counting, and then another loop to construct the filtered list? Probably even has better performance, I think `O(n)`. (1 iteration to do the counts, 1 iteration to re-construct the new list)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [fedekau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34935696/3789665)'s approach, but not counting:

```
int[]numbers = {9,1,2,4,1,2,2};
int guessedDistinct = (int)(2 * Math.sqrt(numbers.length));
final Map<Number, Boolean>
    seenBefore = new HashMap<>(guessedDistinct);
for (int i : numbers)
    seenBefore.put(i, seenBefore.containsKey(i));
int[] out = Arrays.stream(numbers)
    .filter(i -> seenBefore.getOrDefault(i, false))
    .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out));
```

(or try to avoid "finding i twice" in filling `seenBefore`:

```
for (int i : numbers)
    seenBefore.compute(i, (k, seen) -> null != seen);
```